# WCF CORs Globel.asax VS web.config

Tags: c#, wcf, cors, access-control

Hey all I have the following in my **Global.asax** file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Pragma, Cache-Control");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

I run the **WCF** and test it out using the following:

```
function ajaxGetData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:62755/TutorialService.svc/Tutorial',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
            failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error: ", jqXHR);
        }
    });
}

function ajaxPostData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:62755/TutorialService.svc/Tutorial/1',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({"Tutorialid": 1}),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
            failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error: ", jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

That works just fine for both **GET** and **POST**. However, if I comment all that out above and use the **Web.config** and structure it just like the **Global.asax** file like so:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Pragma, Cache-Control" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

It works for get **GET** but not the **POST**. Post error in the console saying:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:62755/TutorialService.svc/Tutorial/1' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think this is related to your issue, but you should be aware that an origin `*` can't be used with auth headers.  See the [MDN page on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials).  Scroll down to "Credentialed requests and wildcards."

Comment: I kind of recall this issue a while back, I believe it has something to do with `OPTIONSVerbHandler` or adding `IsapiModule`

Comment: Indeed, the default `web.config` adds `OPTIONSVerbHandler` which tells IIS to ignore that verb.

Comment: @penleychan seems you are somewhat correct. If I take out **<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />** it runs just like the Globala.sax version does :) Feel free to make this an official answer.

Comment: No worries, I wouldn't even know how to explain that in an official answer. web.config does some weird stuff sometimes.

Comment: Well actually it didn't seem to fix it. Must have been a catch version instead of the refreshed changed web.config file

Answer (score 1):

In my case , I solved my problem with configuring cors in web.config by adding the following code to global.asax to ensure every option method will have a 200 status code.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        }

    }
```